# Transmission for variable-speed flywheel to output a steady output speed?

Tags: mechanical, transmission

If you had a flywheel acting as a mechanical battery in an all mechanical system, such that you could pump energy into the flywheel up to a desired speed and then slowly drain its kinetic energy - then how could you **mechanically** transmit this power at a constant output speed, no matter how fast or slow the flywheel moves? Obviously there will be a minimum speed threshold to drive the output, but we want a constant speed from its upper rpm limit down to this threshold.

Comment: So not electric, then research cvt transmissions - actually used in  a few cars - DAF iirc but 40 odd years ago...

Comment: Do hydraulics count as mechanical?

Answer (score 0):

The flywheel can pump air into a sealed container with a check valve.

So the container will act as a regulator to keep the outlet air at say a steady 100psi, even though the container pressure could vary between say 5kpsi and 200 psi.

There is a wide number of pneumatic storage and distribution of energy at work in many contexts and applications, which can be modified for this purpose.

**Edit**

OP asks for no electrical systems, otherwise there is already working magnetically controlled gyros for the exact same purpose

Comment: Unfortunately, pneumatic storage systems are notoriously inefficient. The heat generated by compressing the air is lost to the environment over a fairly short time. The system then becomes "chilled" when the air pressure is released and contains less energy than that which was placed in the container. Air powered vehicles have been attempted and have vanished.

Answer (score 0):

The DAF Variomatic transmission is/was a transmission based on a vee-belt and two pulleys.

The space between the pulley faces was controlled to give the "gear ratio" ie driven pulley effective diameter compared to the driver pulley effective diameter.

The torque capability was a limiting factor so worked well for smaller engine size cars.

This is but one link for moreinfo : https://www.uniquecarsandparts.com.au/how_it_works_variomatic_transmission